# Refreshing content UITextView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, uitextview

I've got a textView on my main view. I have got a button, on pressing takes me to next view that has a UITextField.

When I type a sentence, it appears on my textView. But my problem is, When I go back on hitting the button and type another sentence. The second sentence also gets displayed with the earlier one.

I have googled, is there a way to update the changes? Or should I write any delegate to update changes. Please help me out with this.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want only the second message to appear try to use

```
yourTextView.text = yourString;
```

or

```
[yourTextView setText:yourString];
```

if you want the second sentence to appear on another line, use

```
[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@\n%@", yourTextView.text, yourString];
```

I do believe there is some method for appending string, but I don't know it by heart.

Answer (score 0):

**

> hi. do one thing make one delegate object like string and store your
>   text field value in this and when you came back in your main view
>   assign that delegate string in to your textview so it wll run
>   perfectly.

**

Comment: Yeah even I hope that must work fine, wil try and rep you. 
Thanks for the ans.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem I faced was with, not knowing how loadView works.

The textView has to be allocated only once, So even if we try to add for second time.. it adds. Multiple declaration must not be done.